# Getting the maximum key (argmax) of the nested dictionary inside a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

(Python) So I have a nested dictionary set up something like:

```
{spanish word: {english word: .5, english word 2: .3, ...}}
```

where the keys are spanish words, and the values are nested dictionaries whose keys are english words and their probabilities.
And I want to get the spanish word such that it has the maximum value.
I've tried (for a current spanish word)

```
maxenglish = max(d[word], key = d[word].get)
```

but this returns the english word. I'm not too familiar with lambda functions, but I saw that could be employed? Thanks for the help!

Edited: Switched English and Spanish

Example:

```
nesteddict = {"hola": {"hello":.5,"goodbye":.1}, "ciao": {"hello":.1,"goodbye":.5}
word = "hola"
argmax = max(nesteddict[word], key = nesteddict[word].get)
```

returns "hello," but I want it to return "hola".

Comment: Could you provide concrete values and expected inputs / outputs for the English / Spanish words?

Comment: You say `returns "hello," but I want it to return "hola".`...but `hola` is the word you are starting with. You already have that value in the variable `word`.

Comment: @Mark Yes, the more I'm editing the question the less it's starting to make sense. Hmm

Answer (score 0):

Would this be something you require? It takes the dictionary and the word for which the most appropriate translation is needed. As such it returns the best suited word by getting the max score.

```
def get_best_word(nesteddict, wd):
    max_score = 0
    key_with_max_score = ""
    for k in nesteddict:
        for sk in nesteddict[k]:
            current_score = nesteddict[k][sk]
            if sk == wd and current_score > max_score:
                key_with_max_score = k
                max_score = current_score
    print(key_with_max_score)
```

Or you can do this using the max function by passing a lambda function as argument to the key
`max(nesteddict.keys(), key=lambda k: nesteddict[k]["hello"])`

But the latter will throw an error if there is no `hello` key in all the nested dictionaries

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to build a noisy channel decoder with this but it didn't end up working out (it didn't finish translating a document in 5 hours and what it did was about 20% accurate). The problem I ran into was trying to get the english characters to pass into bigram probabilities hence the question I asked, but the more I worked on it the less it made sense.